# Can't run Alter Table command due to locks

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, alter-table

I'm unable to drop, delete or alter a database in my Local SQL Server instance.

I have run `sp_Who2` and there don't appear to be any processes using the database apart from a process which gets spawned by my issuing the `Alter Database` command (I do this against the `Master` db). This process has a `Wait type` of `LCK_M_X` and a value of -2 for the `Blocked By` attribute.

I have issued `KILL` commands against them and I've restarted all the related system services and my machine a few times but to no avail. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: -2 is an [DTC transaction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/04/20/how-it-works-orphan-dtc-transaction-session-spid-2.aspx). What else is going on? And try this http://www.sqlserverclub.com/articles/how-to-deal-with-negative-spids-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Please see the screenshot here: http://www.largedocument.com/4/ec24da47/dbLockIssue.PNG - I can't see anything too suspicious apart from the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop (do your alter) and start DTC and [all will be fine](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/SQL-Server/32159723/alter-database-set-single-user-blocking.aspx).